# Sorted array in Java: how can I implement?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

1. Implement a function that examines an array and returns 0 or 1,
   where 0 indicates the array is unsorted and 1 indicates the array is
   sorted.
2. If array is unsorted, Implement a selection sort that removes
   duplicates during the sorting process.

Comment: what did you try? Is it homework? If it is - please tag it as such.

Comment: Is that your homework assignment? If so, at least try to do it yourself...

Answer (score 2):

Point 1 should be easy:

```
loop through the whole array
{
    if (array[THIS INDEX] > array[THIS INDEX + 1]) //the element before is greater than the next one
        ARRAY IS NOT SORTED
}

//IF LOOP IS COMPLETED AND CODE REACHES THIS POINT
ARRAY IS SORTED
```

Comment: Do not feed answers to homework questions, as the tag explicitly says: `This lets potential answerers know that they SHOULD guide the student in solving the problem, and SHOULD NOT simply show the complete answer.`

Answer (score 1):

1. An array is sorted if and only if for each `i` in
   `[0,array.length)` the expression `array[i] <= array[i+1]` yields true (make sure you understand why this constraint is important).
2. Implementing a selection sort is fairly simple; look at the [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Algorithm) in Wikipedia.